# Appending a scene and materials do not come through

Tags: materials, append

So I spent several hours making this blender scene for school: [image]

I figured I would be able to append it into my current project:
[image]

I entered a separate layer to try and add the text to the snow.blend, but when I added it, it appeared with no materials/different lights/nodes not coming through etc.

It appended and appeared like this:[image]

HELP ME PLEASE!!

Comment: both scenes are very different. Your text uses front and backlight, your moutain scene uses a sun from the right and an environment texture. the sun is probably on a different layer but the environment is used on all layers. Can't say more without the  [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)